# Specifying number of cells in LSTM layer in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I don't fully understand the [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) layer in PyTorch. When I instantiate an LSTM layer how can I specify the number of LSTM cells inside the layer? My first thought was that it was the "num_layers" argument, if we assume that LSTM cells are connected vertically. But if that is the case how can we implement stacked LSTM with for example two layers with 8 cells each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of cells of an LSTM (or RNN or GRU) is the amount of timesteps your input has/needs. For example, when you want to run the word „hello“ through the LSTM function in Pytorch, you can just convert the word to a vector (with one-hot encoding or embeddings) and then pass that vector though the LSTM function. It will then, in the background, iterate through all the embedded characters („h“, „e“, „l“, ...). And each input can even have a different amount of timesteps/cells, for example when you want to pass „hello“ and after that „Joe“ the LSTM will need different amount of iterations (5 for hello, 3 for Joe). So as you can see, there is no need to give an amount of cells! Hope that answer satisfied you. :)

**Edit**

An example:

```
sentence = "Hey Im Joe"

embedding_size = 300
batch_size = 1  # batch-size 1 for demonstration

input_ = [create_embedding(word, dims=embedding_size) for word in sentence]
# the LSTM will need three timesteps or cells to process that sentence 
input_ = torch.tensor(x).reshape(1, embedding_size)

hidden_size = 256
layers = 256

lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=layers, dropout=0.5, batch_first=True)

# initialize hidden-state (must be tuple of following dimentsions
hidden = (torch.zeros(layers, batch_size, hidden_size), torch.zeros(layers, batch_size, hidden_size))

outputs, hidden = lstm(input_, hidden)
# outputs is now a list containing the outputs of each timestep
# for classification you can take output of the last timestep and use it further, like this
output = outputs[:, -1]
```

So what happens in this (`outputs, hidden = lstm(input, hidden)`) line?
Again pseudo code:

```
# inside the LSTM function

# lets say for demonstration reasons the embedding for "Hey" is a, for "Im" its b and for "Joe" its c

input_ = [a, b, c]

def LSTM(input_sentence):
    hidden = ...
    outputs = []
    
    # each iteration is one timestep/cell
    for embedded_word in input_sentence:
        output, hidden = neural_network(embedded_word, hidden)
        outputs.append(output)
    
    # returns all outputs and hiddenstate (which you normally dont need)
    return outputs, hidden

outputs, hidden = LSTM(input_)
```

Is it clear now how what the LSTM function does and how to use it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. If for example I use GloVe embeddings (300 dims) and I want to feed an entire sentence of lets say 5 words to the model, I would have 5 300-dim vectors. But how can feed the entire sentence at once, like LSTM(list_of_embeddings)? I would need to have 5 distinct LSTM cells, right? And I can't specify the number of cells. I am trying to understand PyTorch implementation based on Andrew Ng's explanation, so that might be helpful.

Comment: You have to pass the entire sentence (a list of 5 300dims embeddings) into the LSTM function. When you pass the list into the LSTM the first element will pass through it, then the hidden state will be saved and used when the next element goes through and so on. The LSTM function iterates through the list. You don’t even have to think about a LSTM as a bunch of cells. Just one neural network that iterates through the elements of the Input  (ie word in a sentence) and takes the hiddenstate of one forward pass and passes it to the next input. When you would program a LSTM yourself, $

Comment: $ you wouldn’t hardcode the cells, you would just iterate through the list which contains the embeddings of the words, Im editing the answer above.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. I have one more question. Can I stack the embeddings of the input words in one tensor matrix? I guess this is what "sequence_len" axis is used for in the input shape?

Comment: I understand it now, thank you! I will mark the question as answered. :)

Comment: That was indeed very helpful. This explanation should also be in the docs in my opinion. Thanks!